# Erro mimetype application/octet-stream em imagem jpeg com Laravel

Tags: laravel, upload, file-upload, mime-type

Ao tentar fazer upload de uma imagem com Laravel percebo um comportamento de código diferente dependendo do tamanho da imagem impedindo o upload do arquivo como demonstro na imagem abaixo que obtenho com a função dd() no Laravel;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da minha função de atualizar o registro com o nome da imagem para fazer o link no html;

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user, $id)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $data = $request->all();
        $resource = $user->findOrFail((int)$id);
        $img = $request->file('image');

        if ($img) {        
            if ($img->isValid()) {
                $nameFile = hash('md5', now()->timestamp) . '.' . $img->extension();
                $upload = $request->file('image')->storeAs(
                    'marca', "$nameFile"
                );
                if (!$upload) {
                    throw new Exception('Falha ao enviar imagem!', '500');
                }
                $data['image'] = $nameFile;
            } else {
                dd(
                    $img,
                    $img->isValid(),
                    $img->getClientMimeType()
                );
            }
        }
        $resource->update($data);
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($exception->getMessage());
    }

    return redirect("/user/$resource->id")->with('saved', "success");
}
```

Porém se eu abrir a mesma imagem no Paint e reduzir o tamanho em porcentagem da imagem para 25% eu consigo fazer upload do arquivo normalmente.

Alguém poderia dizer porque o código se comporta diferente em relação ao tamanho da imagem?

Print dos detalhes da imagem que eu NÂO consigo fazer o upload;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Propriedades da Imagem editada no paint que eu CONSIGO fazer o upload;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: isso é problema do servidor e não do laravel, no site do laravel tem uma api para vc gerenciar as strings pelo metodo get.

Answer (score 0):

veja: https://king.host/wiki/artigo/mimetypes/

Configurar mimetypes em servidor Linux
Caso seu ambiente de hospedagem seja Linux Apache, utilize o arquivo .htaccess para adicionar extensões de arquivo ao seu site.
Segue em um exemplo abaixo (extensão mp4):

## Extensao de video mp4

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

mude video/mp4 para o que você esta querendo permitir,mais toma cuidado, ve-la se vc não faz besteira e abre uma brecha na segurança do server.

```
Lista com os mime-types mais comuns
Extensão    Mimetype    Tipo de arquivo
.7z application/7z  7-Zip
.aac    audio/x-aac Áudio
.apk    application/vnd.android.package-archive Aplicativo Android
.avi    video/x-msvideo Vídeo
.bin    application/octet-stream    Binário
.css    text/css    Folhas de estilos
.doc    application/msword  Documento de texto
.exe    application/octet-stream    Pacotes executáveis
.html   text/html   Hipertexto
.js application/x-javascript    Javascript
.mp4    video/mp4   Vídeo
.pdf    application/pdf PDF
.swf    application/x-shockwave Adobe Shockwave
.zip    application/zip Compactação
```

Answer (score -2):

Opa,

Tive esse mesmo problema, e como última tentativa atualizei o Laravel via composer (composer update na pasta do projeto) e para minha surpresa havia uma atualização do mime, advinha? Tudo voltou ao normal e é vida que segue! Valeeeeu!

Att